# Android list files in private app storage

Tags: android, load, save

I'm developing Android app, and I need save and load functions.

I want to save important data in private app storage with this function:

```
public static void save(Object file, String fileName, Context context)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName,
            context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(file);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
    System.out.println(TAG + ": File saved successful!");
}
```

I've also written method for loading data.
This works because I know the exact name of file.

I need now to do dynamic saving of files, with dynamic generation of names.
How can I list files saved in pricate app storage?
So I can load exact one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go!

```
File dir = getFilesDir(); 
File[] subFiles = dir.listFiles();

if (subFiles != null)
{
    for (File file : subFiles)
    {
        // Here is each file
    }
}
```

Comment: It's returning 0 files...How I can check is it my saved file saved at all? :) I get "File save successful log"

Comment: I've checked file is there...and I successfully loaded it back in app.

Comment: That's because you save the files to different dir than my example.
I edited my answer.

Comment: Though it would probably return a path to the file itself - you'll need to get the dir's path from that String

Comment: I'm not sure what's the dir path. Can you figure it out from save function? im trying com.myapp.example/data

Comment: Mate its pretty simple... But anyway, I've updated the answer AGAIN... :) Hope this help...